# How to draw with SpriteBatch NOT directly to the screen but a Pixmap?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm currently working on a game that is based on a window system (like the Windows (OS) Explorer).

For the sake of performance i only draw a window with all of it's components when it is dirty (with changes that has to be rendered). When drawing a "dirty" window the rendered image is stored in a Pixmap. So, next time the window is rendered, the Pixmap is drawn. Imagine it like rendering only a screenshot of the window. This actually causes a more stable framerate.

But here's my problem:
When the window background is transparent and something in the background changes, these changes are overlapped by the saved Pixmap (screenshot) of the transparent window.

My current solution to this is clearing the background before rendering into the Pixmap. But when I do so all of what's in the background get's flashed away for a frame. Then I tried to save a screenshot of everything drawn so far (background), then draw the transparent window, save it in the Pixmap, draw the background again and the clean Pixmap above it. As you can image this consumes too much rendering time and causes framedrops of over 50% on 1080p.

The optimal solution (imho) would be to always draw a dirty window directly to the Pixmap instead of the screen. Like this it could always be drawn to an empty canvas without interferring with the background. And afterwards the Pixmap would be drawn to the screen. Instead of a Pixmap a ByteArray or anything compareable would be fine too.

I couldn't come up with a way of doing this and didn't find anything useful on google.

~Thanks

Comment: Using Pixmap is almost never a good solution. You want to use a FBO (FrameBuffer Object, or just Framebuffer) instead.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much :) This is exactly what i need